# How do you make a stepper motor move in accordance to earthquake data using arduino?

Tags: motor, stepper

I am new to arduino. I can import the acceleration data from a text file into arduino and I can also make the motor run at that acceleration with a distance calculated from an equation. I use the AccelStepper library but I notice that per acceleration data, the motor stops abruptly and moves  again in a very short delay, causing a lot of vibrations. Is there any easier way to make a stepper motor run with acceleration values from a text file?

The text file is also placed on an SD card, and I use the function Serial.parseFloat() to get the data from the file.

Here is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>
int STP = 4;
int DIR = 3;
const int chipSelect = 53;
double Acceleration = 0;
double Previous_Acceleration = 0;
double Velocity = 0;
double Previous_Velocity = 0;
double Distance = 0;
double Previous_Distance;
AccelStepper stepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER,STP,DIR);
void setup(){
  pinMode(STP,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Serial.println("Starting Program");
  delay(1000);
  while (!Serial){
    ;
  }
  Serial.println("Initializing SD Card...");
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)){
    Serial.println("SD Card Error");
    while(1);
  }
  Serial.println("Card Initialized");

  File dataFile = SD.open("sinx.txt");

  if (dataFile){
    while (dataFile.available()){
      Acceleration = dataFile.parseFloat();
      Velocity = ((Previous_Acceleration + Acceleration)/2) + Previous_Velocity;
      Distance = ((Previous_Velocity + Velocity)/2) + Previous_Distance;
      stepper.setSpeed(Velocity);
      stepper.setAcceleration(Acceleration);
      stepper.runToNewPosition(Distance - Previous_Distance);

    }
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Error");
  }
}

void loop(){

}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the values you are getting out of your file reading and calculations are actually correct?

Comment: Yes, they are the same values if applied in Excel.

Comment: However, when ran, the motor stops after a loop is done and resumes. The delay is so short that it seems that it runs continuously, but this causes vibration of the motor causing the readings of the accelerometer to be inaccurate. This may be the cause of a blocking function ( I am inexperienced so I may be wrong ), so is there any way to make the stepper motor move with acceleration without putting distance?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? Would like to hear from you if you were able to solve it.